# Angularjs: How to apply a CSS property to a single element generated by ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm generating some div tags with the ng-repeat directive. What I'd like is that when the user hovers over one of the div tags, only that div tag will change its background. However, as it stands, when the user hovers over the tag, all the ng-repeat generated elements have the property applied to them.

Here's my code for the element:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat="verb in verbArray | filter: filterText" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" 
             ng-mouseenter="changeColor(true)" ng-mouseleave="changeColor(false)"
             ng-style="highlightColor">
                {{verb.name}}<img src="{{verb.presentImage}}"/><img src="{{verb.pastImage}}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the changeColor function in the controller

```
    $scope.changeColor = function(theBool) {
        if(theBool === true) {
            $scope.highlightColor = {'background-color': 'green'};
        } else if (theBool === false) {
            $scope.highlightColor = {'background-color': 'white'}; //or, whatever the original color is
        }
    };
```

How can I make it so that the only thing that has the changeColor function applied is the element that's being hovered over?

Thank You for the help

Edit: If I did it with CSS, would it work like this:

```
            <div ng-repeat="verb in verbArray | filter: filterText" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" 
             ng-mouseenter="changeColor(true)" ng-mouseleave="changeColor(false)"
             ng-style="highlightColor" class="classOne">
                {{verb.name}}<img src="{{verb.presentImage}}"/><img src="{{verb.pastImage}}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS file

```
.classOne:hover {
 background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: How about adding a custom attribute and populating it via $index. Then target the one you wish tp

Comment: [hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp), please read

Comment: @Tushar. I'm sorry. I'm very new to AngularJS and Javascript in general. I don't really know the ins and outs of the language yet. How do I make a custom attribute? How do I use this $index service. Do I need to inject it into my controller?

Comment: @Tushar. I got it to work through CSS. However, I'm curious about the method you mentioned. I think it may come in handy in the future. Could you please let me know where I might find more information about this topic? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to obtain this effect with the **:hover** selector (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

like this:

```
div:hover {
    background-color:green;
}
```

doing this through CSS is generally faster than using Angular to do it.

Comment: Thanks, but how do select a div to apply it to. Should I assign the div with the ng-repeat in a CSS class and apply it to that class?

Comment: Yes, that is a great idea, you could name it something like .listitem and apply the CSS rule on .listitem:hover